# How do I stop this algorithm loop?

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, genetic-algorithm, stl-algorithm

I was trying to get the Negmax algorithm in my program. I understood it, but I am also a little doubt on the algorithm anyway. But after currentDepth reach to depth's maximum, it has to stop this loop. Please help me to solve this?

In other words, if the current depth is larger compared with maximum depth, it must stop the loop. But it will not happen here, please help me stop this loop. Thanks in advance.

However, Here is the problem, I put some methods also, but it is not worked, Therefore, I deleted and put as comments what I had experimented. This is a part of my code:

```
if(currentGameDepth == maximumGameDepth)
        {

           // I included some methods, but it won't execute to out of the loop
            // I tried to return Mathf.Infinite(), but it is not work..
            // please help me
           //-----------------------------------------------------------------

        }
```

The full code given as follows:-
Here you can see, two places add `NegamaxAlgorithm` keyword:
The Negmax Algorithm is down here:-

```
private static float NegamaxAlgorithm(Piece game, float maximumGameDepth, float currentGameDepth, GamesModel moves)
{ 
    if(currentGameDepth == maximumGameDepth)
    {

       // I included some methods, but it won't execute to out of the loop
        // I tried to return Mathf.Infinite(), but it is not work..
        // please help me
       //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    }

    bestGameMove = null;
    float bestGameScore = Mathf.NegativeInfinity;
    foreach (GamesModel m in MovesList1)
    {
        Moves move = Piece.AccordaingToEvaluationWhiteSide(m,game);
        float recursedGameScore;
        Moves currentGameMove = move;
        recursedGameScore = NegamaxAlgorithm(game , maximumGameDepth , currentGameDepth + 1, currentGameMove);
        float currentGameScore = -recursedGameScore;
        if (currentGameScore > bestGameScore)
        {
            bestGameScore = currentGameScore;
            bestGameMove = m;
        }
    }
    return bestGameScore;
}
```

..

Comment: You would usually stop a loop by using the keyword `break;` inside it, but you're confusing me. Because your `if` statement is outside the loop to begin with.

Comment: Yeh I was tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Even I used void methods and experimented, it is also did not worked.

Comment: @MustafaAlAmeen - That is the algorithm format, I can't touch and change the format of the algorithm.

Comment: I am unaware of what you're trying to achieve, since you cannot change the algorithm it's self.

Comment: If depth is an `int` use an `int` to represent it. `floats` don't compare for equality so well because of floating point representation issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably that you are using floats to represent an integer depth and the `==` comparison is failing due to floating point precision issues.

Try something like:

```
private static float NegamaxAlgorithm(Piece game, 
     int maximumGameDepth, int currentGameDepth, GamesModel moves)
{ 
    if(currentGameDepth >= maximumGameDepth)
    {
        // terminate recursion
        return float.MinValue;
    }
    else
    {
       // ... use recursion to calculate next level ...
       return bestGameScore;
    }
```

}

Comment: But how do I stop?. I tried everything.. Using on Mathf technique, I tried to use break statements. But all are did not worked..

Comment: @HamunSunga provided you return a value and provided the comparison between depths works the recursion will terminate. Add a print statement showing currentGameDepth and maximumGameDepth to the start of the method. Does it behave as expected? Did you add back the return statement too inside the if?

Comment: @HamunSunga if you don't return a value or don't wrap the rest of the method in an else it will keep recursing. See edit above which now does both (just for clarity).